# Not navigating to configured search result page

Tags: sxa-search

I am very new to Sitecore. In our project, we need to implement the SXA out-of-the-box Site Search. I tried creating a scope and adding an SXA Search Box to a page and gave the Scope for search. Also created a Search result page where I created a Search rendering to render the result. But, on clicking of search, it is not navigating to the search result page I have specified in the Search Box control properties.
Can someone point me to any simple document to implement SXA OOTB Site Search?

Answer (score 1):

**Add the Search Box rendering:**  To change the Search Box rendering properties,  in the Search Box toolbar, click More, and click Edit component properties. In the Control Properties dialog box, select the specific page in the *Search results page* field.

[image]

In the above screenshot, you can see, we have selected the Search page under the home node.

Basically, you need to create a search page item under the content tree.  The search results page is a separate page on your website that has the Search Results component. This page acts as a landing page that shows search results when users perform a search from anywhere on your site. Typically, this page also contains other relevant search components, for example, Search Box, Page Selector, Sort Results, and some filters. If a Search Box component has the Search results page parameter configured, it redirects to this search results landing page.

For more details, you can refer to this document: https://doc.sitecore.com/en/users/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/walkthrough--adding-search-functionality-to-your-page.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.
Few more questions on this:
1. Do we need to set scope and other search parameters on search box and search result both?
2. How do we create search scope for searching all the pages and files in the sitecore?

Comment: @ImranShahid To redirect on the search result page, no need to set scope. To search across all the pages leave the scope empty.

Comment: We got the answer for our issue. We had our own Themes folder and there was no Search Theme, adding which from the Base Themes the search functionality is now working.